Trying to interact with smartContract(deployed on hardhat) using ethers
Error fetching rocket status:

Error: could not decode result data (value="0x", info={ "method":
"status", "signature": "status()" }, code=BAD_DATA, version=6.12.1)

function I am calling-
const fetchRocketStatus = async () => {
  try {
      const provider = new ethers.JsonRpcProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545/');
      const signer = await provider.getSigner();
      const contract = new Contract(contractAdress, abi, provider);
        const rocketStatus = await contract.status();
        console.log("Rocket Status: ", rocketStatus);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching rocket status: ", error);
    }
}

I try to interact with my smartContract
Hardhat is used to deploy contract and ethersjs is used to call function
One thing is shown is log-
WARNING: Calling an account which is not a contractFrom: 0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266
To 0x5fbdb2315678afecb367f032d93f642f64180aa3`

You haven't properly deployed the contract.

It's deployed. I am getting parameters like getBlockno.
